# In the global search, change the user operator to identify network profile id

Tags: feature-request, search, stackexchange.com, global-search

The new-ish [global search on stackexchange.com](https://stackexchange.com/search) has great potential. One thing it can achieve, in theory, is let us search in all posts of a specific user, on all sites.

However, at this point it's only in theory since the user operator still gets only a per-site user id, and the results are based on that.

To solve this, we should be able to give the network user id as value of user operator (or just the `user:me` as already exists on the sites), and the internal search will take the proper per-site id based on that. Ideally, [this query](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A201110+is%3Aq) will show all my questions all over the network for example, but for now it's just showing questions posted by users who happen to have my network profile id as their per-site id:

> [image: search results not ideal]

Can this please be done?

Comment: I would add a note, if a user decide to hide his communities, maybe the request could respect that and not show them, as the query will easily find all communities a member is active on.

Comment: @yagmoth555 makes sense, indeed.