# Searching for own unanswered questions seems to no longer work

Tags: support, search

I am trying to get a list of my unanswered questions (or questions with no accepted answer) across the Stack Exchange network.

There is an [old meta question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141179/view-my-unanswered-questions) asking exactly that. Its answer suggests a query syntax using the "me" user shortcut combined with an answer predicate like so:

```
user:me hasaccepted:no
```

This is also what the "advanced search tips" link right next to the search field suggests. However, this does not work for me, neither on sites where I am logged in and try with `me`, nor on sites I am not logged in and try with `jstarek`. In both cases, I get very long lists of questions including entries where I did not submit the question.

Did the syntax change? What could be going wrong there?

Comment: I don't think that ever worked across all sites. Only per site.

Comment: But I currently see it failing also on individual sites...

Comment: it seems to work for me: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A578411+hasaccepted%3A0&mixed=0

Comment: On which site are you trying this?

Comment: It works for me too. For a cross-network solution, try [rene's SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/790652/find-all-my-unaccepted-question-network-wide).

Comment: Stackexchange "mother" (as a logged in user), Unix&Linux (as a logged in user), Stackoverflow (not logged in).

Comment: Unix & Linux works for me a well for your account: https://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A7932+hasaccepted%3Ano and does the search on [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A175651+hasaccepted%3Ano) and [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A585820+hasaccepted%3Ano&mixed=0) also works for me, even in incognito mode.

Comment: SE main uses google dosen't it?

Comment: Aaargs... ok, my mistake. I missed the fact that the numerical ID is different on each site, not global across the network. Sorry about the noise. 

What's best practice here on meta, delete the question or write a proper answer?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek not anymore. It also is on Elastic now.

Comment: @jstarek yeah, your accountid is equal across all sites but your userid isn't. That is indeed assigned per site. user:me should always work.

Comment: Maybe an answer is in order. Do know there exists this FR: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/310653/in-the-global-search-change-the-user-operator-to-identify-network-profile-id

Comment: also related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119575/how-can-i-view-all-my-unaccepted-questions-across-se/259795#259795

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Summarizing all the helpful information in the comments and from elsewhere:

The Stack Exchange network itself (and its individual sites) do *not* provide a way to list one's own unanswered questions.

The [previous meta question about the same topic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141179/view-my-unanswered-questions) does indeed give a working workaround:

```
user:me hasaccepted:no
```

works on individual (!) sites where one is currently logged in.

As others have remarked in the comments, the Stack Exchange Data Explorer does provide the basis for such a query across the entire network, see user rene's "[Find all my unaccepted question network wide](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/790652/find-all-my-unaccepted-question-network-wide#resultSets)".

Depending on your use case, the latter method might yield the most helpful results, e.g. if you want to see if you have any answered questions where you just forgot to accept an answer. However, it seems that the SEDE dataset is not updated daily.

Comment: Correct, SEDE is updated once a week, on Sunday at 03:00 UTC.