# Search only my posts across all sites

Tags: discussion, support, search, global-search

I wrote a post some years ago about a relatively complex bash script (with parameters) but I can't find it anymore, and I don't remember on which site of the SE hierarchy I wrote it. Is there a way to perform a search across sites, where I can specify the user (me)?

Comment: Not possible with the current search, I've [already asked to make it possible](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/310653/in-the-global-search-change-the-user-operator-to-identify-network-profile-id).

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83570/allow-cross-site-queries-in-data-explorer shows some SEDE queries which might be useful, but that's some Chtulhu voodoo SQL.

Comment: @tripleee thanks, but my faith prohibits me from summoning the Great Old Ones (which I would definitely end up doing, had I to write SQL queries).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there a way to perform a search across sites, where I can specify the user (me)?

Use this [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/398377/dump-of-my-own-stackexchange-content?accountid=169656&opt.textResults=true) to get all your questions and answers across SE, then run a search on it.

Comment: I got a very long answer (looks like HTML) in the Messages window.  How can I download it? Ctrl + A selects all the text in the web page, not just the content of the Messages window. I'm using Chrome on Windows

Comment: @DeltaIV I don't know a better options aside from ctrl+a: [Add option to download a message in SEDE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/392616/178179). In your case you could do the search in Chrome though, without having to download anything.

Comment: Why was this downvoted? So far it's one of the only options available.

Comment: @DeltaIV Can't you do control/command+f on the page itself instead of downloading it?

Comment: Maybe easier to link to the supporting MSE post: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/269804/dump-of-my-own-stackexchange-content

Comment: @DeltaIV better option to copy the message: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/392746/178179

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt fantastic! This  answers my question perfectly

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, there's no network-wide "search" function that allows you to search for just your own posts.

There is, however, a list of all your activity, network-wide, on your network profile:

https://stackexchange.com/users/1893897/deltaiv?tab=activity

Open that, and go to the *"posts"* tab. There you'll find all your questions and answers.
You can even expand individual posts to check if it's the one you need.

Comment: There is a global search [se].

Comment: Hm, I wasn't aware. `user:me` doesn't seem to work there, though. I'm active, but [not __that__ active](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x8TNv.png).

Comment: It does work if you give explicit id, e.g. [this one](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A203057).

Comment: Then why is [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/165550/accessibility-services-get-disabled-automatically) getting returned? I'm not in there...

Comment: @Cerbrus because the userid matches.

Comment: @ShadowTheGPTWizard That returns the posts from all users with that ID, which is a different user on every site.

Comment: @Laurel true, but usually there aren't multiple active users with that same number, so while far from ideal, it usually give decent results. (Though of course you can just search inside that site with the `user:me` operator.)

Comment: It's just a more confusing version of searching for `user:me` on a single site. It doesn't help at all in this case since if it does include posts from other sites, they will not be from the same user.

Comment: @Cerbrus thanks, but it's complicated to go through years of activity to find a post. It would be far more useful if results were at least grouped by site. I guess there's no way of doing what I asked