# Add option to download a message in SEDE

Tags: feature-request, data-explorer

In SEDE, one can download the results as a CSV file, but there are no options to download a message.

Feature request: Add an option to download a message in SEDE. That'd be useful for queries returning long messages ([example](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/398377/dump-of-my-own-stackexchange-content?accountid=169656&opt.textResults=true)).

---

Downloading the results as a CSV:

[image]

Comment: But that "message" is just HTML, how exactly you want to download it? As HTML document? Plain text? You can just copy and paste it. Query results are data tables that can't be easily copied, so the download is useful. but with messages, that's just not the case.

Comment: This would be a pretty simple userscript I believe; it'd just be taking the contents of the message and throwing it into a txt for download... even just a "copy all" button might serve your needs here.

Comment: @ShadowTheGPTWizard Copy-pasting is a bit inconvenient for long messages. Downloading as HTML file or a "copy all" button as zcoop98 suggests would be more convenient. I agree that the CSV use case is stronger.

Comment: As a workaround in Firefox: right-click the panel and `Inspect` it; then right-click the corresponding DOM node and `Copy -> Inner HTML`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Karl Knechtel](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/173477/karl-knechtel) [mentioned](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/392616/add-option-to-download-a-message-in-sede#comment1313165_392616) in a comment, one can use the Inspect feature of one's browser to copy the message. E.g., in Chrome: `F12`, then:

[image]